# nginx configuration for rails subdir deployment

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm having quite a bit of trouble configuring nginx to serve my Rails app's static files; I mean all the files in the app's `public/` folder, not just the files in Rails' asset pipeline.  It seems I'm able to get things mostly working but I can't figure out how to put everything together.  My app is installed in a subdir on the server (`/dashboard`) and not the web root.

Here are excerpts from my various config files:

*config.ru*:

```
map Dashboard::Application.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
  run Rails.application
end
```

*environments/production.rb*:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/dashboard"
config.assets.prefix = "/dashboard/assets/"
```

*nginx.conf*:

```
location /dashboard/ {

    root /srv/XXX/dashboard/public;

    location /dashboard/assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri @unicorn;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}

location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
}

upstream unicorn_server {
    server unix:/srv/XXX/dashboard/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

With this configuration I'm able to serve the Rails app itself using unicorn and the files inside the `public/assets/` folder using nginx, but the rest of the files in the `public/` folder are routed to Rails and end up returning a 404 status code.  I know this is because the server is looking for (for example) `/dashboard/robots.txt` which doesn't exist inside the `public/` folder.  I believe I need to use `alias` to manipulate the paths however I haven't been able to put everything together to get Rails to correctly serve the app and nginx to serve the static files.